# Laravel Passport + VueJS: Unauthenticated error

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, axios

I'm currently building a laravel 5.4 powered page to manage users. I've done all basic pages such as home, login, register, dashboard using blade templating engine. Now I'm building the User Management page. I've successfully **implemented VueJS for this particular page**. All components are working perfectly.

Now the **problem I'm facing now is using Axios to get logged in user data from API route**. At first I'm using usual api route to get auth()->user() data but it doesn't work.

I've learned that I must use Laravel Passport to do this API operation.

These are the steps I made after that:

1. composer require laravel/passport
2. php artisan migrate
3. php artisan passport:install
4. Added the Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens trait to your App\User model
5. Called the Passport::routes method within the boot method of your AuthServiceProvider
6. Set the driver option of the api authentication guard to passport
7. Added the CreateFreshApiToken middleware to your web middleware group
8. Edited bootstrap.js file like the following :

> ```
> window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
>     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
>     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
> };
> ```

9. Axios Code :

> ```
> axios.post('/api/getmydata', {
>     params: {
>         type: 'raw'
>     }
> })
> .then((response) => {
>     console.log(response);
> }).catch((error) => {
>     console.log(error);
> });
> ```

10. Changed route (api.php) :

> ```
> Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function(){
>     Route::post('getmydata', 'ApiController@test');
> });
> ```

11. Added function inside ApiController :

> ```
> public function test() {
>     $user = Auth::user();
>     return $user;
> }
> ```

12. **The problem here is axios somehow return error: Unauthenticated**

Is there anything wrong with my code?
Or is there any other way of achieving this? Thank you

Comment: why you are using `'middleware' => 'api'` inside `api.php` its automatically done by laravel

Comment: `Auth::user()` will not work via `api.php` its sateless

Comment: @user2486 - This is not true. The whole point of using passport is to authenticate API requests using a token. Thus allowing Laravel's Auth functionality to work.

Comment: Do you have the meta tag in your document header which contains the token that Axios uses to send with requests? `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: @Joe yes I do in every page. I checked the response headers, the laravel_token and X-CSRF token is being sent to the API

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is checking your `storage/laravel.log` file, it may be a permissions problem on the generated passport keys.

Answer (score 1):

Send the access token in the header of your API request:

```
Application Type :application/json
Authentication : Bearer [Access-Token]
```